# Program Keeps Crashing when I am Running (with mediaRecoder and Player)

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer, android-mediarecorder

I am not sure why this code keeps crashing. I cannot even open it. Any advice? 
I am trying to have multitrack recording. And here I include 4 track buttons(play, stop and record).

```
package com.audiwave.joe.multitrackaudio;

    import android.content.DialogInterface;
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
    import android.media.MediaRecorder;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        //MediaPlayer
        private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
        private MediaRecorder recorder;

        //FileName
        private String OUTPUTFILE;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            //Buttons
            final Button track1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.track_1);
            final Button track2= (Button) findViewById(R.id.track_2);
            final Button track3= (Button) findViewById(R.id.track_3);
            final Button track4= (Button) findViewById(R.id.track_4);
            final Button Record= (Button) findViewById(R.id.Record);
            final Button Play= (Button) findViewById(R.id.Play);
            final Button Stop= (Button) findViewById(R.id.Stop);

            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            OUTPUTFILE= Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/audiorecorder.3gp";

            //track 1 recording
            track1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){
                    if(R.id.Record==1){
                        try{
                            startRecording();
                        } catch (Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            //track 2 recording
            track2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){
                    if(R.id.Record==1){
                        try{
                            startRecording();
                        } catch (Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            //track 3 recording
            track3.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){
                    if(R.id.Record==1){
                        try{
                            startRecording();
                        } catch (Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            //track 4 recording
            track4.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                public void onClick(View v){
                    if(R.id.Record==1){
                        try{
                            startRecording();
                        } catch (Exception e){
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });

            //Play recording
            Play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    try
                    {
                        mediaPlayer=new MediaPlayer();
                        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(OUTPUTFILE);
                        mediaPlayer.prepare();
                        mediaPlayer.start();
                    }
                    catch(Exception e){
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });

            //Stop recording
            Stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mediaPlayer != null)
                        mediaPlayer.stop();
                }
            });
        }


        private void startRecording() {
            File outFile= new File(OUTPUTFILE);
            recorder= new MediaRecorder();
            recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_WB);
            recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            recorder.setOutputFile(OUTPUTFILE);

            //prepare recorder
            try{
                recorder.prepare();
            } catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            //start recorder
            recorder.start();

        }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();

            //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }

            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

    }
```

Comment: You really should show us your logcat output. You didn't even say what the error is.

Comment: What kinds of errors are getting thrown in the console when it crashes?

Comment: Maybe the buttons must to be declare outside of the `onCreate` method, and then only inizialize them after `setContent`

Comment: @takendarkk I apologize for not showing the logcat output if you were the one to give me a negative. I didn't know how to describe the problem.

Comment: You can edit your question and add it.

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this:

Actually need to set view before initialize UI widgets.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //Buttons
        final Button track1= (Button) findViewById(R.id.track_1);
        final Button track2= (Button) findViewById(R.id.track_2);
        final Button track3= (Button) findViewById(R.id.track_3);
        final Button track4= (Button) findViewById(R.id.track_4);
        final Button Record= (Button) findViewById(R.id.Record);
        final Button Play= (Button) findViewById(R.id.Play);
        final Button Stop= (Button) findViewById(R.id.Stop);

   // Other stuff
}
```

Hope this will help you.